# subordinate clause

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, gerund-phrases

I'm looking for a grammatical explanation for this clause

> Men tend to talk about fewer subjects, *the most popular being work, and sport.*

In other words, we could say "..., among which, work and sport are the most popular". But I can't find a grammatical explanation for the first one ".. being work and sport."

Comment: The clause you quote is perfect.  There is no need to rewrite it.  Also, the rewrite is far more difficult to follow.

Comment: This is a deletion from 'Men tend to talk about fewer subjects, the most popular of these [subjects] being work, and sport.' The tacked-on information is in an adjunct, an absolute clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to phrase it in grammatical terms "being" is a present participle that can replace the finite verb (in this case "are") of a non-restrictive relative clause. The latter is not a subordinate clause but an adjunct (that is it provides supplementary information).

Comment: This one can be added to the list of possible grammatical functions of -ing participial clauses containing a subject, contributed by StoneyB here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105900/understanding-absolute-construction

Comment: Of course I was not claiming that all -ing clauses only replace relative clauses...

Comment: I know, I just thought that it might be useful to put this particular use in the context of the range of other functions that -ing clauses can perform.

Comment: Yes, that's useful.